# Querying SQLite data from specific colums, including an image

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

AuctionList activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.auction_list_activity);

    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AuctionAdapter(this,R.layout.auction_items,list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //DATA QUERY HERE,TO QUERY NAME AND IMAGE

}
}
```

DatabaseHelper5:

```
public class DatabaseHelper5 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static String DBNAME = "Auction";
    private final static int DBVERSION = 2;

    SQLiteDatabase mDB5;

    public final static String TBL_AUCTION = "auction";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_NAME = "name";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_PRICE = "price";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_DURATION = "duration";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_IMAGE = "image";


    private String crt_tbl_auction = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_AUCTION + "(" +
            COL_AUCTION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_AUCTION_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_PRICE + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_DURATION + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_IMAGE + " TEXT " +
            ")";

    public DatabaseHelper5(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB5 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
//1st option:

        {
            String[] columns={COL_AUCTION_ID,COL_AUCTION_NAME,COL_AUCTION_IMAGE};

            return mDB5.query(TBL_AUCTION, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        }


//Second option:

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                COL_AUCTION_NAME,
                COL_AUCTION_IMAGE
        };

        Cursor res = db.query(
                TBL_AUCTION,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null, null, null, null, BaseColumns._ID + " DESC"            
        );

        return res;

    }
```

I would like to query data from my database for name and image which are COL_AUCTION_NAME AND COL_AUCTION_IMAGE respectively.

Comment: What are the issues that you are having?

Comment: @MikeT I do not know how to query data from my DatabaseHelper5 getData() to display in grid view. in the auction list code, i identified to put the codes to query and display in gridview

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :-

```
public Cursor getData() {
//1st option:

    {
        String[] columns={COL_AUCTION_ID,COL_AUCTION_NAME,COL_AUCTION_IMAGE};

        return mDB5.query(TBL_AUCTION, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
} //<<<<<<<<<< Added to make getData a method

//Second option:
public Cursor getDataV2() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {
            COL_AUCTION_NAME,
            COL_AUCTION_IMAGE
    };

    return db.query(
            TBL_AUCTION,   // The table to query
            projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
            null, null, null, null, BaseColumns._ID + " DESC"            
    );
}
```

In you Activity :-

1. define a class member/variable for the DatabaseHelper5 object e.g. `DatabaseHelper5 DBHlpr;`
2. define a class member for the Cursor e.g. `Cursor csr;`
3. use the following to replace **//DATA QUERY HERE,TO QUERY NAME AND IMAGE**

   ```
   DBhlpr = new DatabaseHelper5(this);
   Cursor csr = DBhlper.getDataV2();
   ```

   - Note you should close the Cursor when the activity finishes, so perhaps override the **onDestroy** method to include `csr.close()`.

---

## Limited Working Example

The following code is a limited working example based upon a SimpleCursorAdapter (as per comments).

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    DatabaseHelper5 mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Context mContext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper5(this);
        addSomeData(); // Add some data to DB if none
        manageGridView(); // Manage (setup) the GridView
    }

    /**
     * Should always close a Cursor when done with it
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCsr.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageGridView(); // always refresh
    }

    /**
     * Manage the GridView
     * Will setup the Gridview if not already setup
     * Otherwise will refresh the gridview (after changes have been made)
     * Note how onResume calls this, thus any changes in other activities
     * perhaps started via clicking an auction (see example click handling that Toasts info)
     */
    private void manageGridView() {
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getDataV2();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mCsr,new
                    String[]{DatabaseHelper5.COL_AUCTION_NAME, DatabaseHelper5.COL_AUCTION_IMAGE},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            gridView.setAdapter(mSCA);
            /**
             * Example of handling onItemClick (Toasts info about the clicked item)
             * Typically ID would be passed to another activity via an Intent extra
             */
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            mContext,
                            "You clicked on Auction :-" + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper5.COL_AUCTION_NAME)) +
                                    " Image :- " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper5.COL_AUCTION_IMAGE)) +
                                    " ID :- " + String.valueOf(id),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add some testing data if none exists
     */
    private void addSomeData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper5.TBL_AUCTION) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.addAuction("Auction1","The first Auction","100","2","image1 as a string");
            mDBHlpr.addAuction("Auction2","The second Auction","100","2","image2 as a string");
            mDBHlpr.addAuction("Auction4","The thirs Auction","100","2","image3 as a string");
        }
    }
}
```

### DatabaseHelper5.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper5 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static String DBNAME = "Auction";
    private final static int DBVERSION = 2;

    SQLiteDatabase mDB5;

    public final static String TBL_AUCTION = "auction";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_NAME = "name";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_PRICE = "price";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_DURATION = "duration";
    public final static String COL_AUCTION_IMAGE = "image";


    private String crt_tbl_auction = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_AUCTION + "(" +
            COL_AUCTION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_AUCTION_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_PRICE + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_DURATION + " TEXT, " +
            COL_AUCTION_IMAGE + " TEXT " +
            ")";

    public DatabaseHelper5(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB5 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl_auction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public long addAuction(String name, String description, String price, String duration,  String image) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_AUCTION_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_AUCTION_DESCRIPTION,description);
        cv.put(COL_AUCTION_PRICE,price);
        cv.put(COL_AUCTION_DURATION,duration);
        cv.put(COL_AUCTION_IMAGE,image);
        return mDB5.insert(TBL_AUCTION,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
            String[] columns = {COL_AUCTION_ID, COL_AUCTION_NAME, COL_AUCTION_IMAGE};
            return mDB5.query(TBL_AUCTION, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //Second option:
    public Cursor getDataV2() {

        String[] projection = {
                COL_AUCTION_ID,
                COL_AUCTION_NAME,
                COL_AUCTION_IMAGE
        };
        return mDB5.query(
                TBL_AUCTION,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null, null, null, null, BaseColumns._ID + " DESC"
        );
    }
}
```

### Result :-

[image]

Comment: I've done what you told me to add. there's no error, but when it goes to the activity where the gridview is at, nothing is being displayed. May i know why?

Comment: I'm trying to add this in, i believe this is right, just that I have an error:

    if (sma == null) {
            sma = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,wholegrid,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHelper5.COL_AUCTION_NAME,DatabaseHelper5.COL_AUCTION_IMAGE},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            gridView.setAdapter(sma);
        }

Comment: The error i got was:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [name, image]

Comment: CursorAdapters ( e.g. SimplCursorAdapter) requires a column named **_id**, so add **COL_AUCTION_ID** to the projection so the **_id** is included. For the image column it will get a string value. If the image is stored as a blob this will result in an error. If you actually store a blob you'd have to ask another question as you'd need a Custom Adapter along with a Custom layout and you'd be exceeding the [What topics can I ask about here? - a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I suggest tick this question if it's helped you and ask another question.

Comment: I tried debugging but nothing is being displayed still, there's no error anymore but nothing is being displayed.

Comment: @saapmong question has been updated with a limited working example.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help

Comment: @saapmong if the above helped you resolve the issue and move on then you should tick it as answering your question.

Comment: Hi it works now, but my image is in string, how do i convert it back to an image and display it in my gridView?